# Problem including all files when using Xcode source control

Tags: xcode, github

When setting up source control for one of my Xcode projects, Xcode is ignoring project files that are not in the project's main folder. This project uses some files from an additional folder that are shared by several projects. Is there a way to force Xcode to include those "outside" files in source control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project main folder is also the root folder of your Git repository (meaning it has a hidden `.git` subfolder in it), then no.

Files outside the repository would not be included/tracked inside the repository.
You would need to replicate them somehow inside your Git repository in order to include them.

Comment: Maybe the best solution when using shared files is to create a package dependency with its own source control.

Comment: @UncleKenny True, you can then reference that set of shared files within your own repository, as a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).